# R iGraph graph.bfs and environment

Tags: r, igraph

Having trouble with running Breadth-first search algorithm on a graph, my current concern is with the environment parameter, where the callback function is evaluated.

This is the callback function

```
f.in <- function(graph, data, extra) {
    time <- get.vertex.attribute(graph, "time", index=data["vid"])
    root_time <- get.vertex.attribute(graph, "time", index=extra)
    print(ls(environment()))
    if (time != 0){ 
         time_difference <- time - root_time
         result_list <- c(list(), time_difference)
    }
}
```

This is the context where the functions is called

```
graphs <- decompose.graph(network_graph, max.comps = NA, min.vertices = 0) 
lapply(graphs, function(g){
    v0 <- which(degree(g, mode="out") == 0)
    t0 <- get.vertex.attribute(g, "time", index=v0)
    if (t0 != 0) {
         bfs_environment <- new.env()
         assign("result_list", list(), envir=bfs_environment)
         graph.bfs(g, v0, neimode="in", callback=f.in, extra=v0, rho=bfs_environment)
    }
})
```

Now the print of environment shows me the following variables
"data"      "extra"     "graph"     "root_time" "time"

The question is that when I have passed the environment where the callback function is evaluated, then why the "result_list" is not available? Is there something wrong with passing this environment?
Btw using R 2.15.3 and iGraph 0.7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the documentation states:

> rho:    The environment in which the callback function is evaluated

it means that the passed environment is the `parent` of the callback environment.

So you can retrieve your variable using `get()` and `parent.frame()` functions, as shown in the following example:

```
myCallBack <- function(graph, data, extra) {
  print(ls(parent.frame()))
  print(get('result_list', envir=parent.frame()))
  stop('just to stop at the first call...')
}

# a simple tree with 3 nodes
g <- graph.tree(3, children = 2, mode='out')

bfs_environment <- new.env()
assign("result_list", list(A=3), envir=bfs_environment)

graph.bfs(g, 1, callback=myCallBack, extra=NULL, rho=bfs_environment)
```

Output:

```
[1] "result_list"
$A
[1] 3
```